# Rules- How can I make a variable/token with the site URL minus the language path?

Tags: rules, i18n-l10n

I have created a rule set to handle login redirects for users on my site.  If a user logs in from a page that is set to a different language from that user's language (example: English user logs in on a Japanese page), the user will be redirected to a page with the same language as the page upon which they logged in (in the example, a Japanese page).

To fix this, I want to force my redirects to be the appropriate language path based on the user language.

However, the [site:url] replacement pattern which is provided by Rules includes the language path (because it is the front page).

My front page is https://mysite.com/en.

I want to create a new variable which is the URL of my site minus the language path:
https://mysite.com/

I tried creating a variable of type *text* with a value of

```
<?php substr("[site:url]", 0, -2); ?>
```

but for some reason this just gives me the value of [site:url]; it appears that the substr() function has no effect.  I don't understand PHP very well so I could be missing something obvious-- I just want to remove the last two characters of the [site:url].  How can I do this within Rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Drupal global variable $base_root for that.

Comment: Thanks!  Here's an example of what I added to the redirect to go to the `messages` page: `<? global $base_root;
echo $base_root . "/messages"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Independent from Drupal 6 and 7, `<?php url('<front>'); ?>` should give the path to the front page unless you specify a language.  See [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7)

```
<?php
global $user;
$user->language;
?>
```

You can get the logged in user's prefered language from above snippet.

Comment: WHen I get the front page url, it includes /en (if English).  I want to remove this "/en" from the front page URL, which is provided by default.  In other words, I want the front page URL but without the language path appended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php substr(url('<front>', array('absolute' => TRUE)), 0, -2); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried setting this as a variable (URI and also text) but it didn't work in either case (it still returned the full string).